# I can't install photoshop in ubuntu

Tags: photoshop

the only working solution installing photoshop is wine and wine is not working I also try play on linux which support nvidia and AMD GPU and I had intel graphic card and I love ubuntu but somehow no way to install photoshop in it

Comment: Usually you cannot have 100% efficiency with wine, why don't you use GIMP instead of Photoshop? Besides you can run Photoshop on a virtual Windows.

Comment: Have you thought about running a VM?

Comment: There are some alternatives for linux for photoshop besides gimp.  Unless there is a function of photoshop you must have or you have spent a lot of time learning the ins and outs of photoshop, there are easier apps to install that might do.  Maybe you only need a function that another app can do better instead of a do all app like gimp or photoshop.  Everybody has VLC, but most only use about ten% of what it can do.

Answer (score 2):

Because Wine is an API implementation based in part on servicing undocumented parts of the Windows API (a case in which it's not possible to verify full compatibility), it's not always possible to make every Windows program run under Wine -- and the larger, more complex, and older the program (in terms of maintained life, hence the more patches and add-ons), the more likely it will make some API calls that Wine can't service.

Sometimes this just causes minor issues, like jukeboxes not working in There client; other times it will prevent an installer from completing, or cause a crash when you try to use a particular function, or otherwise make the program nearly or completely impossible to use.

As noted in comments, you would have a much better chance of Photoshop installing and working if you were to run it in a VM; however, there are some potential issues there, as well.  First, you'd have to have a licensed copy of Windows or MacOS to install in your VM; second, you'd need enough system resources to build a VM that can handle Photoshop (from hearing my partner complain about running Photoshop on an iMac, you'd need to allocate at least 16 GB RAM inside the VM, which would require you to have about 20 GB installed on your physical machine).  Then, VMs aren't always perfect, either, especially in terms of their use of hardware and hardware drivers, though some are better than others.

What I'd suggest if you *need* Photoshop and can't accomplish what you need in GIMP (possible, since Photoshop adds features and functions much more rapidly than GIMP) is to set up dual boot and reboot to Windows or MacOS for Photoshop sessions, then return to Ubuntu for other activities.  I've run dual boot in the past, and it's annoying at best -- but it does allow native installation and use of software that doesn't play well with Wine.  Additionally, if you have an actual Mac or Hackintosh, it allows use of MacOS and Mac versions of software; in some cases this is a significant improvement over Windows versions of the same software (and sometimes this works the other way).